# Custom color for Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: taskbar, colors, windows-10

It seems that I only can select among some predefined colors for the taskbar in the **Personalize** section.

I already tried the regedit hack (HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize\SpecialColor) without success.

BTW I'm using W10 Home version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're looking in the wrong place. Here's an export of my cyan taskbar, start menu, and active title bars:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"Composition"=dword:00000001
"AccentColor"=dword:00c3b700
"ColorPrevalence"=dword:00000001
"ColorizationGlassAttribute"=dword:00000000
"ColorizationColor"=dword:c400b7c3
"ColorizationColorBalance"=dword:00000059
"ColorizationAfterglow"=dword:c400b7c3
"ColorizationAfterglowBalance"=dword:0000000a
"ColorizationBlurBalance"=dword:00000001
"EnableWindowColorization"=dword:00000001
```

Edit the colorization color (ARGB) and reboot, or don't reboot and [simply use themes to style your GUI:](https://winpeguy.wordpress.com/2015/11/05/win10-personalization-colorization-color-and-headaches/)
[image: Custom ARGB colors in theme]